# Why I can't show my list from another method?

Tags: java, arrays, list, methods, return

Can you tell me why I can't see my list when I try to start it from another method? Below methods:

```
public class CollectionsOperation {
    private  List<Client> bufferedReaderClientLIst = new ArrayList<Client>();
    private  List<Client> emptyBoxForCf = new ArrayList<Client>();
    BufferedReader bf = null;


    private static final String fileName = "Clients.txt";

    public List<Client> bufferedReaderCollection() throws IOException {
        String line;        

        bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8"));

        while((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {

               String[] split = line.split(";"); 
               String nameCompany = split[0].substring(2);
               String adress = split[1]; 
               String phoneNumber = split[2]; 
               String emailAdress = split[3];

               Client k = new Client(nameCompany, adress, phoneNumber, emailAdress);
               bufferedReaderClientLIst.add(k); 
        }
        System.out.println(bufferedReaderClientLIst); 

        return bufferedReaderClientLIst;

    }
    public void show() throws IOException {
        CollectionsOperation k = new CollectionsOperation();
        k.bufferedReaderCollection();
        System.out.println(bufferedReaderClientLIst); 
    }
```

Calling the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        CollectionsOperation k = new CollectionsOperation();                
        k.show();
}
```

And this is the result what I get:

```
[ MarkCompany';Ilusiana';0982882902';mark@company.com,  CorporationX';Berlin';93983';X@Corporation.com]
[]
```

Why the second list is empty ? the method `bufferedReaderCollection()` returns a result and the list `bufferedReaderClientLIst` is available to all methods. What is wrong?

Comment: Why does `show()` create another `CollectionsOperation` object?

Answer (score 3):

In `show()`:

```
public void show() throws IOException {
    CollectionsOperation k = new CollectionsOperation();
    k.bufferedReaderCollection();
    System.out.println(bufferedReaderClientLIst); 
}
```

You create another `CollectionsOperation` object to call `bufferedReaderCollection()` on. This is unnecessary.

However the problem is in the last print statement where you print `bufferedReaderClientList`. This is printing the `bufferedReaderClientList` of the `this` instance, not `k`. Because you have not called `bufferedReaderCollection` on `this`, the list will be empty, hence the `[]` printed at the end.

Instead of creating another instance, use `this`:

```
public void show() throws IOException {
    this.bufferedReaderCollection();
    System.out.println(bufferedReaderClientLIst); 
}
```

Comment: Now is ok. Thank You for answer.